# How many "right-commutative" binary functions are there for sets of size |L| and |R|?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Given two finite sets $L$ and $R$, how many functions are there

$$f: L \times R \to L$$

Such that:

$$\forall l, r_0, r_1. f(f(l, r_0), r_1) = f(f(l, r_1), r_0)$$

Can this be expressed in terms of $|L|$ and $|R|$? Also, is there established terminology for this kind of function (since I just made up "right-commutative")?

**Edit:**

I've computed some of the values numerically, though the complexity quickly blows up so I haven't computed more than this:

```
| L \ R | 0 |     1 |     2 |     3 |      4 |    5 |     6 |     7 |   8 |
|-------|---|-------|-------|-------|--------|------|-------|-------|-----|
|     0 | 1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |      1 |    1 |     1 |     1 |   1 |
|     1 | 1 |     1 |     1 |     1 |      1 |    1 |     1 |     1 |   1 |
|     2 | 1 |     4 |    10 |    22 |     46 |   94 |   190 |   382 | 766 |
|     3 | 1 |    27 |   141 |   573 |   2121 | 7557 | 26601 | 93813 |   ? |
|     4 | 1 |   256 |  2824 | 21088 | 136528 |    ? |     ? |     ? |   ? |
|     5 | 1 |  3125 | 71565 |     ? |      ? |    ? |     ? |     ? |   ? |
|     6 | 1 | 46656 |     ? |     ? |      ? |    ? |     ? |     ? |   ? |
```

Some patterns are clearly visible:

- When $|L|$ or $|R|$ are $0$ then the answer is $1$ (since there's only one map out of the empty set).
- When $|L| = 1$ then the answer is $1$ (since there's only map into the singleton set).
- When $|R| = 1$ then the answer is $|L|^{|L|}$ (since this is equivalent to just counting unary operations on $L$).
- When $|R| = 2$ we get [sequence A181162](https://oeis.org/A181162) (thanks google!)
- When $|L| = 2$ we get $3 \times 2^{|R|} - 2$

I still haven't found a closed form for this though...

Comment: To me it seems more natural to phrase this object as a collection of functions $\{f_r\colon r\in R\}$, where each $f_r\colon L\to L$; the "right-commutativity" condition is now just that the functions $f_r$ all commute with one another.